# How can I create an effective private route using the latest version of react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, routes

I've looked online and most questions uses a different version of react-router-dom than what I'm using making the answer hard to find. What I want to do is simple, let's say a user is logged in then I wouldn't want that user to access the "sign-up" page and redirect them to the "home" page.

Here's the code I'm using that isn't working.

```
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import "firebase/auth";
import {Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'

function AuthRoute ({element: Element, ...rest}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()

    return (
    
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
          return !currentUser ? <Element {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" />
        }}
      ></Route>
    )
}

export default AuthRoute;
```

Here's how it's being called in App.js

```
return (
<Router>
<div className = "App">
<AuthProvider>

<Routes>

    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
    <AuthRoute exact path = "/sign_up" element= {SignUp} />  
    <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
    <Route exact path="/login" element={<SignIn/>}/>
   
</Routes> 
</AuthProvider>
</div>
</Router>
);
```

It routes to sign_up but it doesn't matter if the user exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need help with this but I found how to do it,
first your home route should be an exact path, then in AuthRoute() component you can do this:

```js
export default function AuthRoute ({chidren}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()

    if (currentUser){
        return (children)
    }else{
        return <Navigate to='/sign_up' replace/>
    }
}
```

then in App.js:

```js
<AuthRoute exact path = "/sign_up" element= {SignUp} /> // should be :

<Route path='/sign_up' element={<AuthRoute> <Home/> </AuthRoute>}
 </Route>
```

hope this can help anyone struggling with react-router v6 (like I did)